# IndexPath of a cell when Pinches?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, row, pinch, nsindexpath

I am finding when tableview is pinched with UIPinchGestureRecognizer declaring at `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. Now want to find indexPath of a particular cell that was pinched. so i wrote the like this...

```
- (void)pinchDetected:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer*)gestureRecognizer {
    CGPoint p = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:tblAccountsList];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [tblAccountsList indexPathForRowAtPoint:p];
    NSLog(@"indexPath.row = %@", indexPath.row);
    UITableViewCell *pinchedCell  = [tblAccountsList cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSLog(@"pinchedCell = %@", pinchedCell);
}
```

Problem is in indexPath.row and cell both cases value am getting is null.

So, plz can someone help me to find the indexPath or row that was pinched.

Comment: What value you are getting for `CGPoint p`?

Answer (score 1):

in cell for row method, set cell.tag = indexpath.row  and

in - (void)pinchDetected:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer*)gestureRecognizer
use UITableViewCell* cell = (UITableViewCell*)recognizer.view again from cell.tag you can get the row index.

Comment: No, Iam not using custom cell. Again its showing null for cell.tag

Comment: UITableViewCell *cell = [tblAccountsList dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
 cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    cell.tag = indexPath.row;

        UIPinchGestureRecognizer *pinchRecognizer = [[UIPinchGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(pinchDetected:)];
        [tblAccountsList addGestureRecognizer:pinchRecognizer];
        [pinchRecognizer release];

Comment: If use [cell addGestureRecognizer:pinchRecognizer]; or [cell.contentView addGestureRecognizer:pinchRecognizer]; like this the selector method wasn`t getting called at all....

Comment: u clarify me one thing, if pinching is done from 2nd row and 5th row.. do you want both these rows.. or u want any one row..

Comment: I want a particular cell that was pinched i.e one row.

Comment: can u tell me in brief why u are opting for pinch instead of did select.

Comment: I want to display data of the cell in a subview which should come as a popup when pinched...

Comment: then you need to get the row by calculating the x&y points from its touches-- initial touch & final touch points